# Making div element focusable by click

Tags: html, focus, three.js

I have a div (for a THREE.js visualization) and I need it to be focusable on click. I have tried changing tabindex to 1 or -1, and when it is 1 the element can be focused using tab, but neither of these make it focusable by click. I am on chrome for mac, so I think it might be due to the way mac handles focus ?

Thank you

Comment: have you a link or a jsfiddle or a codepen ?

Comment: WebGLRenderer/CSSRenderer/CanvasRenderer? Methods differ. Please put link to codepen/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an onclick attribute to set focus:

```
<div tabindex="1" onclick = "this.focus();"></div>
```